# ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255) in SELECT

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

What is the cause that can raise a DataIntegrityViolationException in a select statement? I checked and I only have 1 character varying(255) in my table and it's for both records 15-20 characters long.

If I try to get only one entity by Id it works, but if I try to select one by one from a loop of ids, It gives me the error only at the second record, no matters what it is and for the others works!

Comment: I would suggest trying to run the raw SQL query directly against Postgres, which might result in the same error.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've tried and it does not, it works.

Comment: Can we see the exact stack trace and error message? Can you figure out the exact SQL statement that causes the error (look into the PostgreSQL log file).

Comment: Thank you, I find out looking in logs - I though it was from a select, but actually it was from an update statement that I did not know it was executed. I didn't know to look in the Postgresql logs, thanks for the trick!